# React Make re-usable input field for URL to replace non http to http

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to write a reusable component for the input field for `URL`

```
import React from 'react';


const InputURL = ({ nam, ...rest}) => {

    return (
        <>
           <input
               name={name}
               {...rest}
            />
        </>
    );
}

export default InputURL;
```

I want when user input `facebook.com` then in `onChange` it should return with `http` like it will be `https//facebook.com`

I will use only this `<InputURL onChange={(e) => console.log(e)} />`

Can anyone please tell me how can i override `onChange` to replace non `http` to `http`?

**Note: I want to write the condition once in the `InputURL` component only, dont want to write everywhere where i will use it**

Comment: I want to write the condition once and use everywhere

Comment: Have you found any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';


const InputURL = ({ nam, prefix, ...rest}) => {

return (
    <>
    <input
        name={nam}
        id={"input-"+nam}
        onChange={(e) => {
            const value = e.target.value;
            const input = document.querySelector('#input-'+nam);
                if(value.substring(0,prefix.length) != prefix)
                {
                    input.value = prefix;
                } 
        }}
        {...rest}
        />
    </>
);
}
export default InputURL;
```

This should work, check it out the reference of Substring [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Comment: LOL, I want to re-use the inputURL with onChange, i dont want to write every this condition

Comment: please remove your answer, you didnt follow my porblem

Comment: @anamul Got it! in this case is simple, jus put this onChange I've wrote on <input> tag inside your component, then everytime you call <InputURL> the onChange function will be working. In case you want more generically, you can pass the prefix "https//" as props, then calculate substring by the .length prop.

Comment: How? i have tried lots of way, it doesnt work

Comment: I edited my answer, check it out.

Comment: PLease dont post without test, also it doesnt work, have you tested it?

Comment: You use yoru componet like this `< InputURL onChange={(e) => console.log(e)} >/`

Comment: Well, try it now.

Answer (score 0):

onChange event may trigger many time so it would be better if you make your logic to add "http" on blur event like this.

```
import React from 'react';

const InputURL = ({ name, callback, ...rest }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <>
      <input
        onBlur={() => callback(`http://${value}`)}
        name={name}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        {...rest}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default InputURL;
```

and in the component where you are using this component find parameter coming in callback.
for example I am logging here.

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import InputURL from './InputURL';
export default function App() {
  const callback = (val) => {
    console.log('>>>>>', val);
  };
  return (
    <div>
    
      <InputURL callback={callback} name="My Input" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

See SS hope you are looking the same.[image]